# Automate submitting a file

Tags: wpf, file-upload, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF WebBrowser application and I would like automate uploading a file on an html page. I was hoping something like this might work, but it doesn't:

```
string _inputId = "File_Input";
string _attrName = "value";
string _attrValue = "C:/MyFile.txt";

((mshtml.IHTMLElement)doc.all.item(_inputId)).setAttribute(_attrName, _attrValue);
```

I imagine it has something to do with not being able to set that value in JavaScript. Is there a way around this?

Thank you

Answer (score -2):

use ftp to upload file, you cant upload in this way.